# Include an already open file in PHP?

Tags: php, stream, include

I'd like to `include` an already opened file. As include wants a filename this seems untrivial.

The only thing I can find on http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php is to somehow coax the file descriptor out of the return value of `fopen` and use `php://fd/$fd`. I can't get any further.

Edit: apparently it is not clear, I would like to reuse the file descriptor and not reopen the file.

Comment: What do you mean already open? Already included?

Comment: $fp = fopen('foo.txt', 'rw'); // futz with $fp; include "trickystream//something/" . transform($fp);

Comment: "I would like to reuse the file descriptor and not reopen the file" -- Why? Perversity?  What is this going to save or improve?  OK you could save the position, read the file into a variable, exec it, and reseek the position, but again why??

Comment: Sorry midfart -- I meant eval not exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you.  Depending on how the stream was opened, it might return either the full path name or just the base name, so you'll probably have to do some munging to check and make sure the right path is supplied.  (Or the script is run from the correct directory.)

```
<?php

    $fh = fopen('include_source.php', 'r');
    $md = stream_get_meta_data($fh);
    include $md['uri'];
?>
```

Comment: Added clarification to my question. Otherwise, yes, this is a good one.

Comment: What do you mean by "reuse the file descriptor"?  What exactly are you trying to do that this doesn't accomplish?  The file handle isn't altered by the call to stream_get_meta_data or the include file.  Are you saying that you want to do something like include a file that is input from a command prompt or something?

Comment: Something like that, I want to read the header of a file then hand it over to include for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temp file:

```
$return_to_position = ftell($fp);
$temp_path = tempnam('/tmp', 'INC');
$temp_fp = fopen($temp_path, 'w');
rewind($fp);
while(!feof($fp)) {
   fwrite($temp_fp, fread($fp, 1024));
}
fclose($temp_fp);
fseek($fp, $return_to_position);
include $temp_path;
```

**edit** as an in-memory alternative

Similar to my previous answer, but completely in memory... and using the *dreaded* eval()... (**don't hate on eval**: this is equivalent to the previous answer in terms of security) (I mean, the idea in general makes me uneasy... but it's cool to try and solve ;-)

**NOTE** eval does not like php tags, this may not work if the file has them...

```
$return_to_position = ftell($fp);
rewind($fp);
$fp_php_code = "";
while(!feof($fp)) {
  $fp_php_code .= fread($fp, 1024);
}
fseek($return_to_position);
eval($fp_php_code);
```

Comment: This is a very slow solution :(

Comment: You may see different performance by tuning the 1024 constant there... But I agree, by it's nature it's writing to the disk a bunch of bits which are already there.

Comment: If it's the disk-access which is slow, you can use eval() as an alternative with a local variable to hold the script. This is ugly, ugly stuff... but it's perhaps worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are after, but if it's something like adding classes dynamically (as opposed to procedural code), you could explore the *experimental* [PECL extension bcompiler_read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcompiler-read.php)

Apparently you can give it a file descriptor and it will read it and create classes... seems pretty cool.

There is also [runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), which allows runtime manipulation of several facets, including class hierarchy. Also experimental.